Simulate paint balls hitting a surface, then dripping
I want to simulate: fire some paint ball particles against a surface and then have these turn into liquid geometry that will have them splatter and then drip down the surface.
In this example I use two particle systems to fire a few objects spread out across two sets of frames, using an object that is a Liquid goemetry.
This isn't working because I imaging that by the time the paint particle geometry is fired, the geometry has already been simulated and no more water particles are available as the object hits the particle/fluid collision surface.

Perhaps I could make the particle instances real, but then it appears that I'd have lots of work to be keyed for a short as a short inflow -- how would I find the exact collision moment?  Or perhaps just keep as a constant inflow and have the object-particle killed upon collision?

As Emerson-Lake-Palmer once wrote: "confusion will be my epitaph".
My example: 
